# Upserts with a script gives me a null pointer exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and I am testing the starter commands. I created an Index, added a document updated it with a simple update. now I am trying to make a scripted update with an upsert tag in the post request. I receiv a null pointr exception as shown below.

```
POST products/_update/1
{
    "script" :"ctx._source.price += 5",
    "upsert" : {
        "price" : 1
    }
}
```

I received the following instead of success

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[DESKTOP-IGOE2EN][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "runtime error",
      "script_stack": [
        "ctx._source.price += 5",
        "                     ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script": "ctx._source.price += 5",
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason": null
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a condition to check if the field (price) exists before accessing it by adding a if() condition:

```
POST products/_update/1
{
    "script" :"if(ctx._source.price!= null) {ctx._source.price += 5"},
    "upsert" : {
        "price" : 1
    }
}
```